# Using Shiny to update dataframe values and access it in the local environment after Shiny session ends

Tags: r, shiny

I have been going through most of the Q&As related to dataframe manipulation within Shiny and I still don't understand how to do something which, in my mind, should be very simple. I don't have experience writing Shiny apps and I'm still struggling with concepts like reactive events.

I have a dataframe A, loaded into R. I want to be able to see a specific value in a specific column in the dataframe in the UI and then edit it. After I edit the dataframe, I want to close the Shiny app and then see the edited dataframe in the Environment tab of RStudio. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Can you add some code to your example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might be a workable example.

Assume `df` is your data frame (I used `iris` to test, commented out below). Create a `reactiveVal` to hold your data, and use for editing with `datatable`. After editing, you can store the data back into your global environment dataframe `df` with `<<-`. An alternative is to do this when exiting the shiny app (such as through the `onStop` or `session$onSessionEnded` method).

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

#df <- iris

ui <- fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput('data'),
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  rv <- reactiveVal(df)
  
  output$data <- DT::renderDataTable ({
    DT::datatable(rv(), editable = TRUE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$data_cell_edit, {
    info <- input$data_cell_edit
    newdf <- rv()
    newdf[info$row, info$col] <- info$value
    rv(newdf)
    df <<- rv()
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Alternative with replacing global `df` on exiting (requires `session`):

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveVal(df)
  
  output$data <- DT::renderDataTable ({
    DT::datatable(rv(), editable = TRUE)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$data_cell_edit, {
    info <- input$data_cell_edit
    newdf <- rv()
    newdf[info$row, info$col] <- info$value
    rv(newdf)
  })
  
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    df <<- isolate(rv())
  })
  
}
```

If you don't want to use reactive values, I suppose you could try the following. This can update your data.frame in the global environment as edits are made. Note that `server = FALSE` is added to handle changes in pages:

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$data <- DT::renderDT (df, editable = TRUE, server = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$data_cell_edit, {
    info <- input$data_cell_edit
    df[info$row, info$col] <<- info$value
  })

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this very informative answer! I had one more question: why do I need to use reactiveVal? Is it because the Shiny server doesn't contain a mutable dataframe otherwise?

Comment: I usually am using reactive values to handle interactivity with inputs, etc. for other apps. I suppose you could do something else if you wanted to without `reactiveVal` (see my edited answer, last example). If you use `server = FALSE` you can make changes to your data frame in the global environment without reactive values, I believe this could work as well.